# Is there tree-based numeral system?

Tags: trees, number-systems

Preferrably such that ((()) ()), (() (())), (((()))), (() () ()) all were different numbers and any tree can be a number.

Comment: The set of finite trees is countable, so yes, there is one (there are a lot, in fact). Is there a nice, intuitive one? I don't know.

Comment: You could apply [shortlex order](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortlex_order) to your parenthesis notations for trees, sorting `(` before `)`, and associate each tree with the number of predecessors it has in that order. This is conceptually simple, but the actual translation is pretty ugly in both directions.

Comment: This isn't such a bad question. Why has it got all those close votes? All the OP is basically asking is: "Is there a compact, stringlike notation for trees that's easy to reason with?"

Comment: @goblin I agree with you, but perhaps the author should explain in more details what is a "tree-based numeral system".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These trees are known as rooted ordered trees or plane trees and their number linked to Catalan numbers (http://oeis.org/A000108). Paper with such numeral system: [A numeral system for the middle levels](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.0995v21.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

One can represent finite trees by a Dyck word, that is a word of the context-free language $D^*$ generated by the grammar $S \to (S) + SS + 1$.
The following article gives several possible enumerations for $D^*$:

Zoltan Kasa, [Generating and ranking of Dyck words](http://www.acta.sapientia.ro/acta-info/C1-1/info1-9.pdf), *Acta Univ. Sapientiae, Informatica*, **1**, 1 (2009) 109–118

See also this paper:

Yu. S. Medvedeva, Fast enumeration of words generated by Dyck grammars, *Mathematical Notes* **96**(1-2):68-83, July 2014

Comment: Can you link to an explanation of that notation? The grammar, I mean.

Comment: @goblin For the grammar, you can look at [Well-formed parentheses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Well-formed_nparentheses). Here $1$ denotes the empty word.